# Error ping sound using Visual C++ and MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, audio

Is there a basic function call in MFC that simply plays the input error ping?

I am looking for something analogous to the AfxMessageBox() call that simply plays the ping that is frequently heard when an error is made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for [MessageBeep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680356(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Specifically, call MessageBeep(MB_OK) for the default beep sound.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712879(VS.85).aspx):

```
PlaySound( (LPCTSTR)SND_ALIAS_SYSTEMHAND, NULL, 
           SND_ALIAS_ID | SND_ASYNC ); // or so
```